# Return All Months & Years Between Date Range - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm a bit stumped how I might go about this.

I have a very basic query, that currently returns sales for each product, by year and month.
It is grouping by year/month, and summing up the quantity. 
This returns one row for each product/year/month combo where there was a sale.

If there was no sale for a month, then there is no data.

I'd like my query to return one row of data for each product for each year/month in my date range, regardless of whether there was actually an order.

If there was no order, then I can return 0 for that product/year/month.

Below is my example query.

```
Declare @DateFrom datetime, @DateTo Datetime
Set @DateFrom = '2012-01-01'
set @DateTo = '2013-12-31'

select 
Convert(CHAR(4),order_header.oh_datetime,120) + '/' + Convert(CHAR(2),order_header.oh_datetime,110) As YearMonth,
variant_detail.vad_variant_code,
sum(order_line_item.oli_qty_required) as 'TotalQty'

From 
variant_Detail
join order_line_item on order_line_item.oli_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
join order_header on order_header.oh_id = order_line_item.oli_oh_id

Where 
(order_header.oh_datetime between @DateFrom and @DateTo)

Group By 
Convert(CHAR(4),order_header.oh_datetime,120) + '/' + Convert(CHAR(2),order_header.oh_datetime,110),
variant_detail.vad_variant_code
```

Comment: I think you need a table with 12 months,simple int column and you JOIN your query with that.

Comment: Problem is I cannot alter the database to add a table to do that.

Comment: Do what Mihai suggests but instead of creating a real table, use a table variable: ``declare @mytable table (id int, name varchar(20))`` Then insert the names into the table variable and join it in your query.

Comment: You can use CTE to make this. You have samples on the web

Comment: Make sure this temp table has the year month combination and not just the months.  One never knows what the input parameters will be.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181286/t-sql-select-get-all-months-within-a-range-of-years)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank your for your suggestions.

I managed to get this working using another method.

```
Declare @DateFrom datetime, @DateTo Datetime
Set @DateFrom = '2012-01-01'
set @DateTo = '2013-12-31'

select 
YearMonthTbl.YearMonth,
orders.vad_variant_code,
orders.qty

From 
(SELECT  Convert(CHAR(4),DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @DateFrom),120) + '/' + Convert(CHAR(2),DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @DateFrom),110) As YearMonth
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @DateFrom, @DateTo)) YearMonthTbl


left join 
    (select variant_Detail.vad_variant_code, 
    sum(order_line_item.oli_qty_required) as 'Qty', 
    Convert(CHAR(4),order_header.oh_datetime,120) + '/' + Convert(CHAR(2),order_header.oh_datetime,110) As 'YearMonth'
    FROM order_line_item 
    join variant_detail on variant_detail.vad_id = order_line_item.oli_vad_id
    join order_header on order_header.oh_id = order_line_item.oli_oh_id
    Where 
    (order_header.oh_datetime between @DateFrom and @DateTo)
    GROUP BY variant_Detail.vad_variant_code,
    Convert(CHAR(4),order_header.oh_datetime,120) + '/' + Convert(CHAR(2),order_header.oh_datetime,110)
    ) as Orders on Orders.YearMonth = YearMonthTbl.YearMonth
```

Comment: +1 In general, pulling a set is going to be more efficient than recursive CTEs. [You might also find this blog series useful](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1).

Answer (score 17):

You can generate this by using CTE.
You will find information on this article : 
http://blog.lysender.com/2010/11/sql-server-generating-date-range-with-cte/

Especially this piece of code :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS cte_start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date) <= @end_date   
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I put together. It will certainly need some debugging, but I think that this will lead you in the right direction. I broke up the queries into different parts in order to attempt to make it easier to read. Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DATETIME, @dateTo DATETIME

SELECT @dateFrom = MIN(oh_datetime) FROM order_header
SELECT @dateTo = MAX(oh_datetime) FROM order_header

;WITH
y AS
(
    SELECT YEAR(@dateFrom) AS [Year]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Year] + 1
    FROM y
    WHERE
          [Year] < YEAR (GETDATE())
),
m AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS [Month]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Month] + 1
    FROM m
    WHERE
          [Month] < 12
),
dates AS
(
SELECT
    CAST(y.[Year] AS nvarchar(4)) + N'/' + RIGHT(N'00' + CAST(m.[Month] AS nvarchar(2)), 2) AS YearMonth
FROM
    y CROSS JOIN m
),
qty AS
(
SELECT
    YEAR(oh.oh_datetime) + N'/' + MONTH(oh.oh_datetime) AS YearMonth,
    v.vad_variant_code,
    oli.oli_qty_required AS Qty
FROM
    variant_Detail AS v
        INNER JOIN order_line_item AS oli ON oil.oli_vad_id = v.vad_id
        INNER JOIN order_header AS oh ON oh.oh_id = oli.oli_oh_id
)
SELECT
    d.YearMonth,
    qty.vad_variant_code,
    SUM(qty.Qty) AS TotalQty
FROM
    dates AS d LEFT OUTER JOIN qty
        ON d.YearMonth = qty.YearMonth
GROUP BY
    d.YearMonth,
    qty.vad_variant_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another twist, if you find all months of a year

```
;WITH DateYear AS (
    SELECT 0 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM DateYear
    WHERE num < 11
)
Select FirstDateOfTheMonth, DATENAME(mm,FirstDateOfTheMonth), num from 
(SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,num,'2017'))  AS FirstDateOfTheMonth, num from DateYear)
cte
```

and the result will be

[image]

Another twist:

```
Declare @dateFrom datetime ='2019-03-21', @dateTo datetime ='2019-12-31'
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @dateFrom AS cte_start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date)
        FROM CTE
        WHERE ( DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date) <=  EOMONTH( @dateTo)   ) 
        --or ( DATENAME(MONTH, cte_start_date) =DATENAME(MONTH, @dateTo) and DATENAME(year, cte_start_date) =DATENAME(year, @dateTo) ) )
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
```

[image]

This below is work for sqlserver 2012 and above to get the last day of the month :-
`Select EOMONTH('2020-02-15')`