# How to calculate number of Orders for given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need some help in writing sql query to capture number of active Orders between date range on month wise grouping. i.e if the user selected 2018-01-01 to 2019-12-31, I have to show number of active orders on a month basis i.e total 12 records.

I'm querying against Order Table whose schema looks like below

```
OrderID    CustomerFirstName   PurchaseDate   OrderEndDate  
1           XYZ                2018-01-01     9999-12-31
2           ABC                2018-02-02     2018-06-30
3           PQR                2018-06-01     2018-06-30
4           GHI                2018-01-01     2018-02-28
```

Order EndDate 9999-12-31 is never ending order.All considers has existing order in all date ranges.

From My UX, if I select Jan to Dec... Results should

JAN   ==> 2 orders
Feb   ==> 3 Orders => Order ID are 1,2,4.

Reason for Month FEB Order ID : 1,2,4 are consider as Active orders because
their end dates are falling in FEB.

For example : ORDER ID : 1 having End date has 9999-12-31 which is never ending. Always Active orders in all the date range

Order ID : 2 having End Date has 2018-06-30 so till June he should be considered has Active order for every Month

Order ID : 4 having end date has 2018-02-28 for Feb month OrderID is active Orders

Expected Output

Month     NoOfOrders

Jan         2

Feb         3

```
Month  NoOfOrder  
Jan      2   
Feb      3
```

Comment: I think you should add expected output as an table just like your sample data for clarity even if you have explained it in the text

Answer (score 1):

Create a year-month table (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542933/9223839)) and join the Order table against it

```
DECLARE @DateFrom datetime, @DateTo Datetime
SET @DateFrom = ' 2018-01-01'
SET @DateTo = '2018-12-31'

SELECT YearMonth, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4),DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @DateFrom),120) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2),DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @DateFrom),110) As YearMonth,
             CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(4),DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @DateFrom),120) + '-' + Convert(CHAR(2),DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @DateFrom),110) + '-01', 23) fulldate
      FROM master.dbo.spt_values x
      WHERE x.type = 'P'        
        AND x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @DateFrom, @DateTo)) YearMonthTbl
LEFT JOIN  Orders o ON YEAR(fulldate) >= YEAR(purchaseDate) AND  MONTH(fulldate) >= MONTH(purchaseDate) and fulldate < = enddate
GROUP BY YearMonth
```

I decided to include also year in output if the input range crosses into a new year

Here is the output for completeness

```
2018-01 2
2018-02 3
2018-03 2
2018-04 2
2018-05 2
2018-06 3
2018-07 1
2018-08 1
2018-09 1
2018-10 1
2018-11 1
2018-12 1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing script, I have doubt on this query, if a purchase is made in previous year and is active till June. it doesn't handle that scenario. I managed to fixed  issue in a different manner. But thanks for sharing script, I got inspired from ur query.

Answer (score 0):

**First Part** - Handling records with `orderenddate= '9999-12-31'`

You can try like following. By putting a `OR` condition for `orderenddate = '9999-12-31'` will make sure that never ending records will eppear in all the searchs if the strat date is within the boundary.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [order] 
WHERE  purchasedate >= @startdate 
       AND ( orderenddate <= @enddate 
              OR orderenddate = '9999-12-31' )
```

**Second Part :**

> sql query to capture number of active Orders between date range on
>   month wise grouping.

For month wise grouping you can try like following.

```
  ;WITH numbersequence( number ) 
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Number 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT number + 1 
         FROM   numbersequence 
         WHERE  number < 12) 

SELECT Sum(ct) ActiveOrderCount, 
       number  AS [month] 
FROM   (SELECT number, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN c.number >= Month(purchasedate) 
                      AND c.number <= Month(orderenddate) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END ct 
        FROM   @order 
               CROSS JOIN numbersequence c 
        WHERE  purchasedate >= @startdate 
               AND ( orderenddate <= @enddate 
                      OR orderenddate = '9999-12-31' )) t 
GROUP  BY number
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/UCYFR93956)

**Output**

```
+------------------+-------+
| ActiveOrderCount | Month |
+------------------+-------+
| 2                | 1     |
+------------------+-------+
| 3                | 2     |
+------------------+-------+
| 2                | 3     |
+------------------+-------+
| 2                | 4     |
+------------------+-------+
| 2                | 5     |
+------------------+-------+
| 3                | 6     |
+------------------+-------+
| 1                | 7     |
+------------------+-------+
| 1                | 8     |
+------------------+-------+
| 1                | 9     |
+------------------+-------+
| 1                | 10    |
+------------------+-------+
| 1                | 11    |
+------------------+-------+
| 1                | 12    |
+------------------+-------+
```

**Assumption** : Start Date and End Date falls under same year. Otherwise you need to put year condition also.