# How Do I Calculate A Running Total That Factors Both Date and Time?

Tags: t-sql, sum, sql-server-2014-express

I have been asked to create a stored procedure that displays rental item quantities across a variable date range. I have a table with the following schema:

```
         --Note that this is condensed, and in reality has proper    constraints
        --and more columns. Many dates from this table are tied to a single
        --ContractDetail (separate table) by ContractDetailId.
        CREATE TABLE RentalContractDates
        (
            RentalDateId               INT IDENTITY(1,1)    NOT NULL, --PK
            ContractDetailId           INT                  NOT NULL, --FK
            RentalDate                 DATETIME             NOT NULL,
            Quantity                   DECIMAL(20,8)        NULL
        );

        INSERT INTO RentalContractDates (ContractDetailId, RentalDate, Quantity)
        VALUES (1, '04/01/2016 3:00 PM', 10), 
               (1, '04/10/2016 1:00 PM', 2), 
               (1, '04/15/2016 11:00 AM', -5),
               (1, '04/15/2016 11:30 AM', -2), 
               (1, '04/27/2016 2:00 PM', -5);
```

Users will enter a date range to search, and the procedure should find all dates that fall within this range, and then also factor in a cutoff time to where a customer would be charged another day on their rentals.

**Example Scenario:** The global Cutoff Time is set to 12:00PM. I have 10 widgets rented on 4/01/2016 at 3:00PM. This basically I means I actually rented them on 4/02/2016 since it is past the Cutoff Time on 04/01. I rent 2 more on 4/10/2016 at 1:00PM, so essentially 4/11/2016. I return 5 widgets on 4/15/2016 at 11:00 AM, and 2 more at 11:30 AM. I want to return all widgets on 4/27/2016, but I arrive past the Cutoff Time of 12:00PM, so rather than get charged for 4/02-4/27, I am actually going to be charged for 4/02-4/28.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** If I had quantities previously rented before 04/01, which is the start of the report range, I would need to include those in the report. For example, if I had 12 rentals on 3/31, 4/1 and on would be adding 12 to their totals. In other words, any previous quantities needed to be calculated into the sum that pulls in with the inputted report @BeginDate and @EndDate parameters.
So 04/01 would read 12, 04/02 would read 22, etc.

As you can see, I do not need users to enter their rentals each day, I just have them set a start date and time for their rentals with a quantity, and the next time they enter a date/time combination it would be re-summed.

**Current Code:** I want to join this query with a list of calendar dates for the entire month, and set their quanties accordingly.

```
        DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME = '04/01/2016',
                @EndDate DATETIME = '04/28/2016';

        DECLARE
                @CutoffTime TIME = '12:00 PM';

        SET @BeginDate = @BeginDate + @CutoffTime;
        SET @EndDate = @EndDate + @CutoffTime;

        SELECT  gbd.ContractDetailId,
                gbd.RentalDate,
                gbd.Cutoff,
                gbd.Quantity,
                'Running Total' = SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ContractDetailId, RentalDate, Cutoff ORDER BY RentalDate)
        FROM    (

    SELECT  
            r.ContractDetailId,
            'RentalDate' = CONVERT(Date, RentalDate),
            r2.Cutoff,
            r.Quantity
    FROM    RentalContractDates r
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                rcd.ContractDetailId,
                'Cutoff' = CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME, RentalDate) >= @CutoffTime THEN 'AFTER CUTOFF' ELSE 'BEFORE CUTOFF' END
            FROM 
                RentalContractDates rcd
         ) r2
        ON r2.ContractDetailId = r.ContractDetailId
    WHERE  
            r.RentalDate Between @BeginDate and @EndDate
    GROUP BY r.ContractDetailId, CONVERT(DATE, RentalDate), r2.Cutoff, Quantity
        ) gbd
        ORDER BY RentalDate, Cutoff DESC
```

I want to join the data with this CTE and set a quantity for every date:

```
        ;WITH T([Date]) AS
    ( 
        SELECT @StartDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,T.[Date]) FROM T WHERE T.[Date] < @EndDate
    )
    SELECT * FROM T
```

**Expected Final Output:**
When complete, the report would end up looking something like this, although it will be pivoted and include the day of the week in the name:

```
    ContractDetailId    RentalDate      Quantity
      ----------------------------------------------------------------
        1               04/01/2016        0  -- 0, because rentals were input after cutoff.
        1               04/02/2016        10
        1               04/03/2016        10 -- Continues until 4/10
        1               04/10/2016        10
        1               04/11/2016        12 -- Continues until 4/15
        1               04/15/2016        5  -- I returned 5 and then 2, so this should sum since both were before the cutoff time.
                                             -- Continues until 4/27.
        1               04/27/2016        5  -- 5, because -5 was entered past cutoff on 4/27.
        1               04/28/2016        0
```

I have the pivoting code along with the dynamic sql necessary for final output already complete (I can post this if requested), but I am lost on how to properly group this data by pre-cutoff/post-cutoff and change the day accordingly. How should I handle this situation? Thank you for any advice/help!

**Edit 1:** Fixed incorrect sample data.

Comment: Your sample data appears to show 12 widgets rented and 14 returned. While that may be a profitable business model, it seems a little off.

Comment: To handle cutoff time simply subtract `12*60=720` minutes from each original `datetime` and after that ignore the time part: `CAST(DATEADD(minute, -720, RentalDate) AS date)`.

Comment: @HABO You're right, don't know how I missed that. 04/15 should be 5. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  --Inputs for your function
    DECLARE @BeginDate DATE = '04/01/2016',
            @EndDate DATE = '04/28/2016',
            @ContractDetailID INT = 1;

    --Defined in the function
    DECLARE @CutoffTime TIME = '12:00 PM';

    DECLARE @PriorSum DECIMAL(20,8) = 0;

    DECLARE @RowCount INT = DATEDIFF(dd,@BeginDate,@Enddate) +1;

    --Get Any quantities before Begin Date
    SELECT @PriorSum=COALESCE(SUM(rcd.Quantity),0)
    from RentalContractDates rcd
    WHERE CAST(CASE when CAST(rcd.RentalDate as TIME) > @CutoffTime THEN DATEADD(dd,1,rcd.RentalDate) ELSE rcd.RentalDate end as date) < @BeginDate
        AND @ContractDetailID = rcd.ContractDetailId

    --Create the Days for the report
    ;WITH RecursiveRowGenerator (Row#, Iteration) AS (
           SELECT 1, 1
            UNION ALL
           SELECT Row# + Iteration, Iteration * 2
             FROM RecursiveRowGenerator
            WHERE Iteration * 2 < CEILING(SQRT(@RowCount+1))
            UNION ALL
           SELECT Row# + (Iteration * 2), Iteration * 2
             FROM RecursiveRowGenerator
            WHERE Iteration * 2 < CEILING(SQRT(@RowCount+1))
         )
         , SqrtNRows AS (
           SELECT *
             FROM RecursiveRowGenerator
            UNION ALL
           SELECT 0, 0
         )
         , Rowtbl as (  
           SELECT top (@RowCount+1) A.Row# * POWER(2,CEILING(LOG(SQRT(@RowCount+1))/LOG(2))) + B.Row# as RowNum
           FROM SqrtNRows A, SqrtNRows B
           ORDER BY A.Row#, B.Row#
         )  
      ,
    DateTable as (

      select top (@RowCount)  DATEADD(dd,RowNum,@BeginDate) AS ReportDate
      from Rowtbl
      where RowNum <= @RowCount  

      )
    ,
    --Merge the days for the report with the actual rental data
    GBD AS 
    ( SELECT  
               @ContractDetailID as ContractDetailID,
                DT.ReportDate AS 'RentalDate',
                CASE when CAST(rcd.RentalDate as TIME) > @CutoffTime THEN 'AFTER CUTOFF' ELSE 'BEFORE CUTOFF' END AS 'Cutoff',
                COALESCE(rcd.Quantity,0) AS Quantity
        FROM    DateTable DT 
        LEFT JOIN RentalContractDates rcd on 
                DT.ReportDate = CAST( CASE when CAST(rcd.RentalDate as TIME) > @CutoffTime THEN DATEADD(dd,1,rcd.RentalDate) ELSE rcd.RentalDate END as DATE) 
                AND @ContractDetailID = rcd.ContractDetailId
        WHERE DT.ReportDate Between @BeginDate and @EndDate 


    )
--Final Select    
SELECT  gbd1.ContractDetailId,
                gbd1.RentalDate,
                (select SUM(gbd2.Quantity) from GBD GBD2 where GBD1.rentaldate >= GBD2.RentalDate) + @PriorSum AS RunningTotal               
        FROM   GBD gbd1     
        GROUP BY gbd1.ContractDetailId,gbd1.RentalDate
        ORDER BY gbd1.RentalDate asc
```

Edit:
The recursive row generator is by Aaron Friel and is my go to solution for generating rows [t-sql select get all Months within a range of years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181286/t-sql-select-get-all-months-within-a-range-of-years/4181313).  It generates rows for all the dates so we can then left join either a quantity or 0 if there is no record for that date.  Generating Dates from 2000 to 2016 is very cheap using this generator.   Joining all the quantities and previous sum to those dates is mildly expensive. Aggregating them so you have a running total even for dates with no record in RentalContractDates is the expensive part.

The part that handles the cut off time issue is:

```
gbd.RentalDate = CAST(CASE WHEN CAST(rcd.RentalDate AS TIME) > @CutoffTime THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, rcd.RentalDate)
            ELSE rcd.RentalDate END AS DATE)
```

It converts rentaldate to a time only, compares to the cutoffTime, adds a day if past and then converts to date only.

Comment: I tested your code and while it works correctly, it slows down heavily when expanding the date range to say, a year or more. When starting at 2000 for the begin date, it took over 1 minute to process. The problem is that I can have quite a few ContractDetailIds (100+), each with many dates, to a single contract that I would be running the report on. I'm modifying it to see if i can take the GBD merge select and move it to a temp table to speed things up. I believe the recursion with the CTE and this select is what slows things down. I will update my original post when I finish. Thanks!

Comment: Completely agree.  I should have been more clear that this solution wasn't meant to be performant on larger date ranges.   I think your approach is good.